# Laravel, WebSockets - Verify user on server

Tags: php, session, laravel, eloquent, ratchet

I currently ran into the problem of handling the authentification of a user on the server, using **Laravel** and **RachetPHP**.

### What I tried so far:

- I changed the driver type of the session to database, giving me an id and payload column. Using `\Session::getId()` returns a 40 character string. 
  The cookie information, sent by the WebSocket-Connection does contain a XSRF-TOKEN and a laravel_session, both containing > 200 characters string. The database ID of the users session differs from the id, returned by `\Session::getId()`.
- I am already sending the current CSRF-token via the websocket message, but I have no clue how to verify it (the built-in verifier uses requests - which I don't have in the websocket server scope).

### Generic Use case:

A User posts a comment in thread. The payload of the sent object would then be:

- Something to verify the user (an ID or a token).
- The comment itself

If you were to send the user ID, anyone could temper the packet and send the message under another ones user.

### My use case:

A user can have *n*-characters. A character has an avatar, an id, a name, etc.
The user is only used to:

- authenticate at the server.
- access his characters, and thus perform basic CRUD operations on his characters.

I also have a table **locations** - a "virtual place", a character can be in... so I got a one-to-one relationship between **character** and **location**. The user (character) can then send messages in a location via websocket. The message is inserted at the database on the server. At this point, I need to know:

- If the user is authenticated (csrf-token ?)
- If the user is the owner of the character (it's very simple to spoof the request with another user's character id)

If you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: Is your Socket-Server (Rachet) part of your Laravel application?

Comment: yes, it is. In fact it's started by an Artisan CLI Command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is how I solved this a while ago. In my example, I'm working with Socket.IO, but I'm pretty sure you can easily rewrite the Socket.IO part to get it to work with RachetPHP as well.

**Socket Server**

The socket server depends on the files [cookie.js](https://gist.github.com/tommyschmiedel/8fb4cd767310ea682f8c) and [array.js](https://gist.github.com/tommyschmiedel/c71f4763c47c1351b73a), and the node modules express, http, socket.io, request and dotenv. I'm not the original author of cookie.js, but there is no author mentioned in the comments, so I'm not able to give any credits for this, sorry.

This is the server.js file which starts the server. It is a simple socket server that tracks who is currently online. The interesting part however is when the server makes a POST request to `socket/auth` on the Laravel application:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app)
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var request = require('request');
var co = require('./cookie.js');
var array = require('./array.js');

// This loads the Laravel .env file
require('dotenv').config({path: '../.env'});

server.listen(process.env.SOCKET_SERVER_PORT);

var activeSockets = {};
var disconnectTimeouts = {};

// When a client connects
io.on('connection', function(socket)
{
    console.log('Client connected...');

    // Read the laravel_session cookie.
    var cookieManager = new co.cookie(socket.handshake.headers.cookie);
    var sess = cookieManager.get("laravel_session"); // Rename "laravel_session" to whatever you called it

    // This is where the socket asks the Laravel app to authenticate the user
    request.post('http://' + process.env.SOCKET_SERVER_HOST + '/socket/auth?s=' + sess, function(error, response, body)
    {
        try {
            // Parse the response from the server
            body = JSON.parse(body);
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            console.log('Error while parsing JSON', e);
            error = true;
        }

        if ( ! error && response.statusCode == 200 && body.authenticated)
        {
            // Assign users ID to the socket
            socket.userId = body.user.id;

            if ( ! array.contains(activeSockets, socket.userId))
            {
                // The client is now 'active'
                activeSockets.push(socket.userId);

                var message = body.user.firstname + ' is now online!';
                console.log(message);

                // Tell everyone that the user has joined
                socket.broadcast.emit('userJoined', socket.userId);
            }
            else if (array.hasKey(disconnectTimeouts, 'user_' + socket.userId))
            {
                clearTimeout(disconnectTimeouts['user_' + socket.userId]);
                delete disconnectTimeouts['user_id' + socket.userId];
            }

            socket.on('disconnect', function()
            {
                // The client is 'inactive' if he doesn't reastablish the connection within 10 seconds
                // For a 'who is online' list, this timeout ensures that the client does not disappear and reappear on each page reload
                disconnectTimeouts['user_' + socket.userId] = setTimeout(function()
                {
                    delete disconnectTimeouts['user_' + socket.userId];
                    array.remove(activeSockets, socket.userId);

                    var message = body.user.firstname + ' is now offline.';
                    console.log(message);

                    socket.broadcast.emit('userLeft', socket.userId);
                }, 10000);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I added some comments to the code, so it should be pretty self-explanatory. Please note that I added `SOCKET_SERVER_HOST` and `SOCKET_SERVER_PORT` to my Laravel .env-file in order to be able to change the host and port without editing the code and run the server on different environments.

```
SOCKET_SERVER_HOST = localhost
SOCKET_SERVER_PORT = 1337
```

**Authenticating a user by a session cookie with Laravel**

This is the SocketController which parses the cookie and responds whether the user could be authenticated or not (JSON response). Its the same mechanism that you described in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439286/laravel-websockets-verify-user-on-server/30441380#30441380). It's not the best design to handle the cookie parsing in the controller, but it should be OK in this case, because the controller only handles that one thing and its functionality isn't used at another point in the application.

*/app/Http/Controllers/SocketController.php*

```php
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\Users\UserRepositoryInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager;
use Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory;

/**
 * Class SocketController
 * @package App\Http\Controllers
 */
class SocketController extends Controller {

    /**
     * @var Encrypter
     */
    private $encrypter;

    /**
     * @var DatabaseManager
     */
    private $database;

    /**
     * @var UserRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $users;

    /**
     * Initialize a new SocketController instance.
     *
     * @param Encrypter $encrypter
     * @param DatabaseManager $database
     * @param UserRepositoryInterface $users
     */
    public function __construct(Encrypter $encrypter, DatabaseManager $database, UserRepositoryInterface $users)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->middleware('internal');

        $this->encrypter = $encrypter;
        $this->database = $database;
        $this->users = $users;
    }

    /**
     * Authorize a user from node.js socket server.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param ResponseFactory $response
     * @param Guard $auth
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function authenticate(Request $request, ResponseFactory $response, Guard $auth)
    {
        try
        {
            $payload = $this->getPayload($request->get('s'));
        } catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            return $response->json([
                'authenticated' => false,
                'message'       => $e->getMessage()
            ]);
        }

        $user = $this->users->find($payload->{$auth->getName()});

        return $response->json([
            'authenticated' => true,
            'user'          => $user->toArray()
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get session payload from encrypted laravel session.
     *
     * @param $session
     * @return object
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    private function getPayload($session)
    {
        $sessionId = $this->encrypter->decrypt($session);
        $sessionEntry = $this->getSession($sessionId);

        $payload = base64_decode($sessionEntry->payload);

        return (object) unserialize($payload);
    }

    /**
     * Fetches base64 encoded session string from the database.
     *
     * @param $sessionId
     * @return mixed
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    private function getSession($sessionId)
    {
        $sessionEntry = $this->database->connection()
            ->table('sessions')->select('*')->whereId($sessionId)->first();

        if (is_null($sessionEntry))
        {
            throw new \Exception('The session could not be found. [Session ID: ' . $sessionId . ']');
        }

        return $sessionEntry;
    }

}
```

In the constructor you can see that I refer to the `internal` middleware. I added this middleware to only allow the socket server to make requests to `socket/auth`.

This is what the middleware looks like:

*/app/Http/Middleware/InternalMiddleware.php*

```php
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory;

class InternalMiddleware {

    /**
     * @var ResponseFactory
     */
    private $response;

    /**
     * @param ResponseFactory $response
     */
    public function __construct(ResponseFactory $response)
    {
        $this->response = $response;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (preg_match(env('INTERNAL_MIDDLEWARE_IP'), $request->ip()))
        {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return $this->response->make('Unauthorized', 401);
    }

}
```

To get this middleware to work, register it in the Kernel and add the `INTERNAL_MIDDLEWARE_IP` property - that is just a regular expression defining which IP addresses are allowed - to your .env-file:

*Local testing (any IP):*

```
INTERNAL_MIDDLEWARE_IP = /^.*$/
```

*Production env:*

```
INTERNAL_MIDDLEWARE_IP = /^192\.168\.0\.1$/
```

I'm sorry I could not help you out with RachetPHP, but I think you get a good idea how this can be solved.

Comment: In the authorize function, how do you inject the Guard instance?

Comment: Laravel injects it automatically, because the controller/method gets initialized by the IoC Container. The framework itself does this with reflection. You can find out more about automatic resolution in [the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ioc#automatic-resolution).

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. Although not very clean, it does what it's supposed to do (I guess...)

The WebSocket-Server gets started by an Artisan Command ([by mmochetti@github](https://github.com/mmochetti/LaravelRatchetChat)). I inject these classes into the Command:

- `Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\Encrypter`
- `App\Contracts\CsrfTokenVerifier` - a custom CsrfTokenVerifier, that simply compares 2 strings (going to put more of the follow logic code in there)

I pass these instances from the command to the server. On the `onMessage` method, I parse the message sent, containing:

- The CSRF-Token of the user
- The character-id of the user

I then check if the token is valid, and if the user is the owner of the character.

```
public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, NetworkMessage $message) {
    if (!$this->verifyCsrfToken($from, $message)) {
        throw new TokenMismatchException;
    }

    if (!$this->verifyUser($from, $message)) {
        throw new \Exception('test');
    }
    ...
}

private function verifyUser(ConnectionInterface $conn, NetworkMessage $message) {
    $cookies         = $conn->WebSocket->request->getCookies();
    $laravel_session = rawurldecode($cookies['laravel_session']);
    $id              = $this->encrypter->decrypt($laravel_session);
    $session         = Session::find($id);
    $payload         = unserialize(base64_decode($session->payload));
    $user_id         = $payload['user_id'];

    $user       = User::find($user_id);
    $characters = $this->characterService->allFrom($user);

    $character_id = $message->getHeader()['character_id'];

    return $characters->contains($character_id);
}

private function verifyCsrfToken($from, NetworkMessage $message) {
    $header = $this->getHeaderToken($from);
    return $this->verifier->tokensMatch($header, $message->getId());
}
```

The code could be cleaner for sure, but as a quick hack, it works. I think, instead of using a model for the Session, I should use the Laravel `DatabaseSessionHandler`.

Comment: This is basically what I did! In my case, I had a nodejs + socket.io server running (I didn't want PHP to handle socket connections). Whenever a client connected to the socket server, I made a request to my Laravel application (SocketAuthController) that parsed the `laravel_session` string and verified the user. I can post my solution if you're interested!

Comment: Yes please. It would be interesting to see your approach.

Comment: When i started working with websockets, i stumbled upon this issue as well. Instead of rolling out my own and banging my head against the wall, i went with pusher instead. There is an open source alternative to pusher: https://github.com/stevegraham/slanger

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel > 5 i use this code:

```
    $cookies = $conn->WebSocket->request->getCookies();
    $laravel_session = rawurldecode($cookies['laravel_session']);
    $id = $this->encrypter->decrypt($laravel_session);

    if(Config::get('session.driver', 'file') == 'file')
    {
        $session = File::get(storage_path('framework/sessions/' . $id));
    }

    $session = array_values(unserialize($session));

    return $session[4]; // todo: Hack, please think another solution
```

To get cookies from client through websocket you must change domain in session config and change everywhere websocket host to your domain:

```
'domain' => 'your.domain.com',
```